# What is the timestamp unit of an exported TwinCAT Scope measurement?

Tags: twincat

I took some measurements with [TwinCAT Scope](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/automation/twincat-3-scope/) and exported the results as a CSV. The measurement series started at 17 August 2022 at 10:32:25.290 which has timestamp 133051987452906875. This is not UNIX time, because that time would correspond to 1660725145. Adding some miliseconds would add some zeros at the end.

So what is the unit of the TwinCAT timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

The same time format is also used at more places. For example in ADS. From the C++ ADS library I found that [the unit is](https://github.com/Beckhoff/ADS/blob/11c8493baa1b750155714d2b2bd7c6fb66785126/AdsLib/standalone/AdsDef.h#L345)

> the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)

Comment: Yep, the time format used by ADS etc. is called Windows `FILETIME`